# Show image in the page after uploading and inserting it to database

Tags: php, html

I want to show the image in my page after uploading and inserting it into the database. The image is used for my image slider. The reason i want to show the image here is to easily manage the image slider. That page is my admin. Im new to php and mysql, can someone give me ideas, what requirements, hints to do it?

here is the picture what i want to do.. like thumbnail
[image]

here is my slider its working.
[image]

**NOTE**: the image button is to upload the image.

here is my image slider code.

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/slider.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: 'fade',
        controlsContainer: '.flexslider'
        });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <?php
                    // Creating query to fetch images from database.
                   $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * from images order by id desc limit 5");
                    $result = $query;
                    while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
                ?>
                    <li>
                    <img src="<?php echo $r['photo'];?>" width="400px" height="300px"/>
                    </li>
                <?php 
                } 
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

here is my admin.php this is where i want to show the image.

```
<?php
//for connecting db
include('connect.php');
if (!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
echo "";
}
else
{
$file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"gallery/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$photo="gallery/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];


$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO images(photo)VALUES('$photo')");
$result = $query; 

echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("image successfully uploaded ");window.location=\'admin.php\';</script>';
}
?>
    <form class="form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="image">
            <p>Upload images and try your self </p>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input class="form-control" id="image" name="image" type="file" onchange='AlertFilesize();'/>
              <input type="submit" value="image"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
```

here is my connect.php code

```
<?php
// hostname or ip of server
$servername='localhost';
// username and password to log onto db server
$dbusername='root';
$dbpassword='';
// name of database
$dbname='pegasus';

////////////// Do not  edit below/////////
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname);
if($mysqli->connect_errno){
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysql->connect_error);
    exit();
}

?>
```

Comment: Why not just reuse the slider in the admin page?

Comment: what do you mean reuse sir?

Comment: <img src="<?php echo $r['photo'];?>" width="400px" height="300px"/> may be file src missing.Please use full path of the image

Comment: there is nothing wrong about the slider sir. its working what i want is to create a like thumbnail to show all the images in the slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use `glob` to see if there are any files in the gallery folder

Something along the lines of:

```
<?php foreach(glob('./path/to/gallery/folder/*.{jpg,gif,png}', GLOB_BRACE) as $image): ?>
<img src="<?= $image; ?>" />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

One benefit of this approach is that if there are no images, nothing will show and you're also saving a db query.

Or to make use of your database query again...

Copy this from your first file..

```
<?php
// Creating query to fetch images from database.
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * from images order by id desc limit 5");
$result = $query;
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
?>
    <img src="<?php echo $r['photo'];?>" width="400px" height="300px"/>
<?php 
    } 
?>
```

and reuse it in your file that you want to display the images

Reference: [`glob`](http://php.net/glob)

Comment: Good day sir. Can you explain the path and the variables there? because i don't know how to apply it into my code if i don't understand it. i have many images in my gallery folder.

Comment: i want to create a like thumbnail there in the box in the picture but all of the image inside it are all images come from my image slider.

Comment: @YukihiraSoma essentially.. glob is looking in the path and fetching an array of matching files ( as $image).. $image (per loop) is a path to an existing image

Comment: i want it to be based on my database sir. how can i do it?

Comment: the image will shown are based on the images stored in the database not just in the gallery folder. is it possible?